# Testing techniques for Apple Push Notification Gateways

Tags: apple-push-notifications

I'm sure this must have been answered but i cant find it.

What are the techniques used to test a server side application that generates apple push notifications?

We have a host based service that waits on an event, and then generates an APN, and our IOS application will receives this notification.

So, I'd like to write a test that simulates the event being received and sends the APN and then determine if it was delivered.  From what i understand, apple will does not support this?

Only think i can think of is to write an IOS application, that simulates the  event has occurred and tells our host to send back a Push notification to the testing device.  Then the IOS application could detect that it was received or not.  We could put it on an IPOD touch that is always running in our server rack.  I dont really like that approach but dont know what else to do.

If we used Urban Airship would that make it easier?

Answer (score 0):

You can send push notification using below url :
http://pushwatch.com/apns/

You'll just need three thing as below :
1)Pem file
2)Device token(s)
3)Message